# Try catch problems

Tags: powershell, registry, try-catch, powershell-3.0

I have the following code where I look up a users SID and if its not found I set an output value to the SID not being found.  I output the entire results to a csv file using a psobject.

Whats happening is that I find an invalid sid and instead of stopping processing the user after doing the following:
$objPrintdata.User_SID_Status ="Invalid SID", it continues to process the same sid and goes to  the $regPrinterDetails.GetSubKeyNames() |ForEach-Object line where it fails and writes another line with the same SID but with the correct error of registry cant be opened and 2003 cant be found.  How can I get out of the loop for the user where I haven't found a SID?

```
Get-Content "P:\PowerShell\jv\servers.txt" | ForEach-Object{
    #Write-Host $_
    $intNumberofServers++
    $strServer =$_
    #setting the psobject server value
    #$strserver
    $objPrintdata.Server = $strServer

    $blnHasOldQueues = $false
    #Setting server value
    $strComputer = $strServer.server

    $PingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $strServer -Count 1 -Quiet
    If($PingResult){
    #Outputting server status
    $objPrintdata.ServerStatus = "Workstation is UP"

        try{
            If($strHklm = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$strServer )){
                #executes when it can open HKLM
                $objPrintdata.RegistryStatus = "Was able to open the registry"
                #set the path of the registry
                $PrinterRegKey = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Print\\Providers\\Client Side Rendering Print Provider'
                $regPrinterRef  = $strHklm.OpenSubKey($PrinterRegKey)   
                #debug
                #$regPrinterRef

            }

            #setting this to output to csv
            # $resultsarray =@()

            #$strPrinters = $regPrinterRef.GetSubKeyNames()
            #check if regprinterref is not null
             if($regPrinterRef){
                #executes when there are keys

                #region Loop thru all child keys. These contain the calculable UNC paths to 2003
                $regPrinterRef.GetSubKeyNames() | ForEach-Object{
                #debug
                # $_
                #concatinating to get to the connections key 
                $strPrinterpath =$PrinterRegKey+"\\"+ $_ + "\\Printers\\Connections"
                #$strPrinterPath
                if ($strPrinterpath -notlike "*servers*"){

                    #this value is the sid
                    # $_  will give us the sids.  Here I am storing the SIDs into strUserSID to use later on
                    $strUserSID = $_
                    #debug
                    $strUserSID      

                    # The logic below will convert SID to username
                    #pass the SID to the secrity principal SID being struserSID
                    #$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("$strUserSID")


                    #using a try catch to filter out deleted SIDs, otherwise powershell will throw an error saying it is null
                    Try{

                       $objSID=get-aduser -filter {sid -eq $strUserSID}

                           if($objSID-eq $null)
                                {
                                    #does a test AD lookup to see if the user still exists baseed on their sid. Returns the user object if it exists & null if not

                                    $objPrintdata.User_SID_Status ="Invalid SID"
                                    $objPrintdata.User = "Invalid SID"
                                    $objPrintdata.Does_it_Have_2003_Queues ="Invalid SID"
                                    $objPrintdata.UNC_2003_Queues = "Invalid SID"
                                    $objPrintdata | Export-Csv P:\powershell\jv\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    #executes when the sid is still valid. Displays a subset of the user object properties
                                    $strUser= $objSID.SamAccountName
                                    $objPrintdata.User_SID_Status ="Valid SID"
                                }                                                                                 

                       }


                    Catch{
                            #$strUserID = $objSID.Value
                            Write-Host "Lost connection to AD"
                            #exit

                        }
                    #$strUser
                    $regPrinterDetails   = $Strhklm.OpenSubKey($strPrinterPath) 
                    #debug
                    #$strPrinterPath
                    #$regPrinterDetails
                    $regPrinterDetails.GetSubKeyNames() |ForEach-Object{
                        #looping through each key at the connections level to search for the 2003 print server names
                        if($_ -like "*sabppprt2*"){

                            $objPrintdata.Does_it_Have_2003_Queues = "Yes"
                            #this value is the printer if it exists
                            # $_ will give us the printers.  Here I am storing the printers into strUserPrinters to user later on
                            $strUserPrinters = $_
                            #$strUserPrinters
                            $blnHasOldQueues = $true
                            #The code below is to build the printer UNC to make it more legible
                            $intPrinterLength= $strUserPrinters.Length
                            $strPrintServer= $strUserPrinters.Substring(2,10)
                            #Doing the -13 because we have to limit the length of the substring statement to the length minus the starting poistion of the substring
                            $strPrinterShareName =$strUserPrinters.Substring(13,$intPrinterLength-13)
                            $strPrintUNC = "\\"+$strPrintServer+"\"+$strPrinterShareName
                            $objPrintdata.UNC_2003_Queues = $strPrintUNC
                            $objPrintdata.User = $strUser
                            # Write-Host $strServer $blnHasOldQueues $strUser  $strPrintUNC
                            $objPrintdata | Export-Csv P:\powershell\jv\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append




                        }


                        # Write-Host $strServer $blnHasOldQueues $strUserSID  $strUserPrinters

                    }

                }
                           else
                           {
                               #Write-host "No 2003 Queues Detected"
                               #Write-host "no 2003 Queues detected" $strUserSID,$strUser,$strPrintUNC
                               $objPrintdata.User = $strUser
                               $objPrintdata.Does_it_Have_2003_Queues = "No 2003 Queues Detected for this user or vsabppprt* queue"
                               $objPrintdata.UNC_2003_Queues = "No 2003 Queues Detected for this user or vsabppprt* queue"
                               $objPrintdata | Export-Csv P:\powershell\jv\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append

                           }

            }
            #endregion
             }

        }
        catch{
            Write-Host  "Can Not access this machines registry:  " $strServer
            $objPrintdata.RegistryStatus = "Can not open the registry" 
            $objPrintdata.User_SID_Status = "Can not open the registry" 
            $objPrintdata.User = "Can not open the registry" 
            $objPrintdata.UNC_2003_Queues = "Could not open the registry"  
            $objPrintdata.Does_it_Have_2003_Queues = "Could not open the registry"
            $objPrintdata | Export-Csv P:\powershell\jv\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append


        }    
    } #if ends here

    else{
        #executes when the machine is unpingable
        Write-Host "This machine is currently not on the network:  "  $strServer 
        $objPrintdata.ServerStatus = "Workstation is Down"  
        $objPrintdata.RegistryStatus = "Workstation is Down" 
        $objPrintdata.User_SID_Status = "Workstation is Down" 
        $objPrintdata.User = "Workstation is Down" 
        $objPrintdata.UNC_2003_Queues = "Workstation is Down"  
        $objPrintdata.Does_it_Have_2003_Queues = "Workstation is Down" 
        $objPrintdata | Export-Csv P:\powershell\jv\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append

    }
    #Doesn't the Else need to be here

}
  $intNumberofServers
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want to stop processing the current child key if you have found an invalid SID. If so just add a `return` statement after the following line:

```
$objPrintdata | Export-Csv P:\powershell\jv\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: It still continues with the return statement.

Comment: With the same SubKeyName or the next one in the list? I would expect the latter

Comment: Just realized what was happening.  I renamed my SID and it picked it up as an invalid SID and still had a reference to my own SID.  Same thing happened when I deleted the SID.  Very strange.